# Changing the preview image when sharing a news article on Facebook?

Tags: facebook, facebook-pages, facebook-timeline, sharing

I want to share an external link (news article) to my company's Facebook page, but the thumbnail is just a generic image showing the name of the news site, so it looks like I'm advertising the newspaper. Is there a web-app or browser extension that allows me to change the preview image to something more relevant to the topic of the article?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You would need to change the [meta tags](http://ogp.me/) of the page you're sharing. If you can't do this (because you don't have access to the site's HTML code or you're sharing an external page), you could try [ShareKit.io](https://www.sharekit.io), which is a web app for changing the Facebook link preview. It also works for other social platforms like Twitter and LinkedIn, as well.